# How could I get a list of unique records from below duplicated records by ignoring first two characters?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the rule:

1. When comparing userId, only search userId starting with 'AB' and its matching duplicates (except 'AB'). Then get a list of "unique userId" by only returning above duplicated userId that is having 'AB' at the beginning.
2. For returned duplicated string starting with 'AB', we need to make sure there is "duplicate"; otherwise, we should not return 0 record

I know it sounds confusing, please see example below:

Table UserName with ten records, and its userId fields (10 records) are:

```
ABC1234
C1234
C12345
BC12345
BBC1234

ABF1235
F1235

ABY1236

BCD3456
D3456
```

Desired Result after running query:

```
ABC1234
ABF1235
```

Please note: Although ABY1236 starts with 'AB', this record should not be returned in output, since it doesn't have a "duplicate" match like Y1236 (ignoring first two character, 'AB').

I have a sample query below, but it only returned duplicated record NOT starting with 'AB', also it will return ABY1236.

```
 SELECT distinct  substr(userId , -(length(userID)-2))
  from  UserName where userId like 'AB%';
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Including @scaisEdge  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EXISTS to check if there is a userId that is equal to the right part of "AB.." starting from the 3d char:

```
select u.userId from UserName u
where 
  u.userId like 'AB_%'
  and
  exists (
    select 1 from UserName where userId = substr(u.userId, 3)
  )
```

Comment: sorry for previous comments, I didn't exactly understand what OP was asking about, your answer seems to be correct

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a selct join for check only the matching result

```
SELECT substr(a.userId , -(length(a.userID)-2))
from  UserName a
INNER JOIN UserName  b ON a.substr(a.userId , -(length(a.userID)-2)) = b.UserId
        AND userId like 'AB%'
```